# Help prove an inequality $C_i^j \le i^{p-1},i \ge p \ge 2, j < p$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Let $C_i^j = \frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}$ denote "$i$ choose $j$". Any one can prove an inequality $C_i^j \le i^{p-1}$ where $i \ge p \ge 2, j < p$?

I attempted $\frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}=\frac{i\times (i-1)\times(i-2)\times...\times(j+1)}{j!}$ with $i-j$ factors as numerator, but I cannot see where the $p-1$ terms of $i$ in the RHS of the desired inequality comes from.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to note that $j \leq p-1$.  We can then calculate:

$$\binom{i}{j} = \frac{i(i-1)\cdots (i - j+1)}{j!} \leq \frac{i^j}{j!} \leq i^j \leq i^{p-1}.$$